# Gnome-Shell behavior in Ubuntu 14.04 is off after installing and then removing Pantheon

Tags: gnome, gnome-control-center, pantheon

I've been using Ubuntu 14.04.1 with Gnome-Shell for a few weeks now and I decided to toy around with pantheon using [this](http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/08/install-elementary-os-pantheon-desktop-environment-ubuntu-14-04/) guide.

I decided it wasn't for me and I removed pantheon via purge. I also cleared all repositories from    `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

After removing Pantheon I came across a few things that didn't work like they used to:

1: Windows/Super Key does not open the overlay anymore. I cannot set this back in key-bindings.

2: Desktop background/appearances no longer works. Right clicking the desktop and selecting 'change desktop background' simply opens the gnome-control-center, where the 'background/appearance' option does not exist. Similarly, there is a 'background' option in the overlay of all my installed applications, however, it does the same as the desktop right-click option.

3: Same as #2 but for backups.

4: Now for some reason, I cannot install the 'places indicator applet' from extensions.gnome.org.

Things I have tried:

Completely remove gnome-shell and all configs and re-installing.

Reverted GTK from 3.12 (needed for Pantheon) back to 3.10(ubuntu stock).

Setting XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME to ensure it wasn't assuming pantheon was the default desktop for some reason.

I have attached a screenshot showing the overlay with the 'background' and 'backups' options available (circled in red). In the bottom-right corner is a screenshot of what my gnome-control-center menu actually has for options. Notice that 'background' and 'backups' are missing.

[image]

Additionally, since I don't feel it deserves a separate question and it isn't the main point of my question here. Does anyone know how to get a bluetooth indicator applet in the panel at the top of the screen? Seriously, that'd be great.

Comment: Update,

It looks like the entry is wrong for the overlay and that's why the program doesn't open.  I can get backups to open if I type 
    /usr/bin/deja-dup-preferences

So there's nothing wrong with the program.  

However, I can't figure out where gnome looks to create it's applications list in the overlay.  

It's not /home/user/.gnome/apps
or
/home/.local/applications

Answer (score 1):

The Application list for Gnomes Overlay is the same as for it's menu You can find the shortcuts in `/usr/share/applications/`

Just copy one file. Python3.3 for example and fit it to your needs. Save it with a new name and sudo rights and your application will be back.

Answer (score -1):

Just had to install blueman like this:

```
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

Got it solved, bluetooth icon is now back in the unity top bar.

Comment: I'm not using Unity.

Additionally, this doesn't really help with the core issue where certain items do not appear in the control center and do not open their respective applications.